# Would magnetic charge (i.e., magnetic monopoles) be Lorentz invariant if it existed?

Tags: special-relativity, maxwell-equations, magnetic-monopoles

Would magnetic charge (i.e., [magnetic monopoles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole)) be Lorentz invariant if it existed?

It is clear that Maxwell's equations in themselves permit magnetic charges but what would their relativistic properties be?

Comment: what makes you think that they wouldn't be Lorentz invariant?